# Small cactus from garden center identification

Tags: identification, cactus

I bought a small cactus from the garden center, but it doesn't say which species it is. Can anyone identify this cactus? For reference I put it next to a coin of about 3 cm (1.2 inch) in diameter. Thanks in advance.

[image: catus]

Answer (score 2):

It's almost certainly a species of Ferocactus.  Unlabeled garden center plants usually are more or less common species... though not always! *Ferocactus haematacanthus* is a very rare species... there is another species with almost the same name-- *F. hamatacanthus* (missing the "e") is much more common.  (The name with the "e", *haematacanthus*, means "blood(red) spines"; without, ie. *hamatacanthus*, means "clawlike or hooked spines".)  But then, juvenile species of the genus often look very much one like another.  I wonder if it is *F. macrodiscus*-- I've seen young plants of this species that look almost exactly like yours... but there are probably  a half-dozen or more others that also do. Blooms might decide it, but apart from *F. fordii*, Ferocactus plants usually won't bloom until they grow very large indeed. After some 4-6 years the adult spination will also aid in identification.  In any case-- it's a really nice plant!

Regards, John in Florida

Comment: Thanks, John. I hope it will bloom, maybe the flowers can tell us more!

Answer (score 1):

Nice plant! I don't have an ID for you. I can tell you it's some sort of barrel cactus. They are hard to ID when they are young (for me, anyway). I recommend repotting it into something a little roomier.

Possibly *Ferocactus haematacanthus*.

Comment: Thanks again, they all look very similar indeed at this stage. So I'll have to wait a few years and post again when it has some flowers (if it will ever bloom here in Holland). I have put it in a little bit larger container already (this one was really small).